# Is this application continuous?

Tags: functional-analysis, analysis

X,Y two vectorial spaces, and T is a linear application from X,which is not empty, to Y. If a is an element of X and y and element of Y. T is defined as: T(a) = y, T(x) = 0 otherwise. Is T continuous?

Comment: It is certainly true that, for all $a\in X$, for all $y\in Y$ and for all linear maps $T:X\to Y$ such that $T(a)=y$ and $T(x)=0$ for all $x\ne a$, $T$ is continuous.

Comment: $T$ is not even linear unless $y = 0$ since $T(2a) = 0 \neq 2y$.

Comment: Sorry, I made a mistake. What I wanted to say is that a is an element of a basis of X, and T is defined as T(a) = y, T(e) = 0 for the other elements of this basis.

Comment: @pdr99 Then, not necessarily. Namely, in an infinite-dimensional Banach space you may complete a basis $\mathcal B'$ of some proper dense subspace to a basis $\mathcal B$ of the whole $X$, and then consider $a\in\mathcal B\setminus\mathcal B'$ and $y\ne 0$.

Comment: @Gae.S. Thank you. I thought of a similar example. However, I do not know how fails the equivalent condition which states that if T  is linear T is continuous if and only if there exists a constant, M >0 which satisfies ||Tx|| < M ||x||. In this case, it isn't certain that ||Tx|| < ||y|| ||x||?

Comment: The point is that if a continuous function is constant on a dense subset, then it must be constant, which such a $T$ is not.

Comment: **There is  no notion of continuity for a function on an arbitrary vector space**.

Comment: @Gae.S. With respect to what topology are you talking about continuity?

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy In the second instance, continuity with respect to the norm I mentioned. In the first comment, it is fairly irrelevant, because constant functions are continuous in any topology and the other cases are vacuously true.

Comment: @Gae.S. What about indiscrete topology?

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy Ah, I see your point. I meant $Y$ to be normed too. but I forgot to wrte it.

Answer (score 0):

I assume $X,Y$ are normed. $T$ may be discontinuous. Choose a Banach space where $a$ lives outside of a dense subset.  For example, let $a = e^x$ in $C([0,1])$ and $T(a) = y = 1 \in \mathbb{R}$.  Defining $T$ such that polynomials lie in the kernel, choose a sequence of polynomials $p_n \rightarrow a$ and let $x_n = a - p_n$.  then $T(x_n) = 1$ for all $n$ while $|x_n| = ||a - p_n||_\infty \rightarrow 0$ which shows that $|Tx| / |x|$ is unbounded.